# phantomjs parses dates incorrectly for dates before March in the year of 1400, why?

Tags: phantomjs

Is it some sort of overflow?

```
phantomjs> new Date("1400-03-01T00:00:00.000Z")
"1400-03-01T00:00:00.000Z"
phantomjs> new Date("1400-02-28T20:59:59.000Z")
"1400-02-27T20:59:59.000Z"
```

what you would expect:

```
>>(new Date("1400-03-01T00:00:00.000Z")).toISOString()
"1400-03-01T00:00:00.000Z"
>>(new Date("1400-02-28T20:59:59.000Z")).toISOString()
"1400-02-28T20:59:59.000Z"
```

apparently there is a gap of 24 hours when parsing dates between the 28th of February in 1400 and the 1st of March in 1400.

### any ideas?

Phantomjs anyway is obsolete but still ... our legacy tests are failing when we try to upgrade to chrome headless ...

Comment: that's interesting, can you hook in different time management library like moment.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS uses a version of [Qt WebKit](http://phantomjs.org/supported-web-standards.html) which is [maintained independently](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14102#issuecomment-198317447) of Qt.

The date format you are using is part of the ISO-8601 date and time format. <sub>[[related]](https://xkcd.com/1179/)</sub>

The version of Qt WebKit that PhantomJS uses has a function that parses dates of the form defined in [ECMA-262-5, section 15.9.1.15](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) (similar to [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) / [ISO 8601](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html): `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss[.sss]Z`).

In the [source code](https://github.com/Vitallium/qtwebkit/blob/phantomjs/Source/WTF/wtf/DateMath.cpp#L726), we can see that the function used to parse these types of dates is called:

```
double parseES5DateFromNullTerminatedCharacters(const char* dateString)
```

The file that contains this function in the PhantomJS repository has not been [updated](https://github.com/Vitallium/qtwebkit/commits/phantomjs/Source/WTF/wtf/DateMath.cpp) since July 27, 2014, while the official file was [updated](https://github.com/qt/qtwebkit/commits/5.212/Source/WTF/wtf/DateMath.cpp) as recently as October 13, 2017.

**It appears that there is a problem in the logic having to do with handling leap years**.

Here is a [comparison of **DateMath.cpp**](https://www.diffchecker.com/mwH7v96Y) between the most recent versions from the official qtwebkit repository (left) and the PhantomJS qtwebkit repository (right).